# Saving to database after designing a form with jQuery/javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a project which allows users to design a small web form. I give them many options such as font style, bold, underline, colors, borders, etc and all changes made are shown in the form preview immediately using javascript.

To give you a better idea of what this does I would say it is a simpler version of the form builders that aweber and getresponse have.

One problem I am face with is because many of the options are done purely through jquery/javacript: color pickers, bold/underline options, border styles, etc, I am wondering what would be the best way to save all of these options to the database once the design is complete?

I have started creating hidden inputs for all of these options and updating the values of these hidden fields when a design option is changed. Then saving all of the options using a normal form submit after the design is finished but I think surely there must be a better or more efficient way to do this?

Does anyone have any opinions on what would be the best/most efficient way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: my two cents: Handling a form post/keeping the hidden form up to date sounds much better than parsing some sort of xhtml dump =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to submitting the form, could you compile all the options to a string value describing the CSS style and save that as 1 field in your table?

Comment: hi, do you mean create the string with javascript?

Comment: @Paul Atkins Yes...  since you're using Javascript to set field values anyway, just set 1 hidden field with "font:bold;text-decoration:underline;color:blue;..." or whatever the appropriate values.  Seems simpler to me than altering multiple hidden fields and then parsing their $_POST values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .ajax() to send the new values to another PHP page that processes the MySQL and updates the table with the users' values, and call .load() on the form div on success to reflect the new settings. But if they make a lot of changes that's heavy on the server. Also, it may require significant restructuring of your script flow.